# Persisting files across reinstalls in app specific directory in Downloads folder

Tags: android, scoped-storage

We have an app that allows users to, among other things, download files and store them locally. To provide greater access to the files (say for example, manual backups), the files are downloaded into an app specific folder in the Download directory.

Till Android Q, the app could simply use the File API to check if the file exists locally and update the UI accordingly. However, since then we've shifted to using the Mediastore API. However, one of the problems faced by users is loss of access to the downloaded files after a reinstall. After a reinstall the app has no way of knowing if a previous install had files left over. It can never properly manage the folder.

The scoped storage documentation says SAF is the way to go give apps full access to read and write to folders. Is there another way? If we are to use SAF, how do we need to request the permission every time the user opens the app? Is there any way to persist the `file` schema URI that is returned? There is little documentation for this use case (either that or we didn't find any).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [the shared storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared). It used for sharing user data that can or should be accessible to other apps and saved even if the user uninstalls your app.

To use it, you need the permission of `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. But when you submit the app to Google Play, there are some limitations there, please read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files).
Because of COVID-19 issue, apps need the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission cannot be uploaded to Google Play. So for now, you can target the SDK version to 29, and use `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag. After early 2021, you can try to use the shared storage.

Comment: The uncertainty of who all will be allowed to use `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is the issue. We don't qualify as a filemanager or a backup app, though the app itself is limited to a small number of users and the codebase is open source.

Comment: Even you want to use SAF, on Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, you cannot use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action to request access to the Downloads directory, which means you cannot list all the files inside the Downloads folder, you can refer [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files).

Comment: Yes. I realize that. My intention with SAF is for the user to give access to a specific folder inside the Downloads folder.

Comment: Another more complex solution is encode all your files in a audio file or image file, and you can query it back by using `MediaStore` API.

Answer (score 0):

For Android 10 devices request legacy external storage in manifest file and you have File access to Download folder as usual.

For Android 11 devices the Download folder is readable in the old way and even writable. No need for media store.

Comment: For Android 11, will I be able to access files of my app after a reinstall? A reinstall of an app is effectively another app when compared to the old app (different uid) if I'm not wrong. I ask this because the documentation for storage for Android R talks about using SAF to access non-media files of other apps (we primarily deal with PDFs, Word Documents, spread sheet etc).

Comment: You can test this all on an Android 11 emulator. I'm not quite shure to be honest.